# Compare two List<E> regardless of order

Tags: java, list

I have two E type lists List list1, List list2. The E object is a POJO class that contains a row of the following data. Both of the lists contain same data. For example at the last column if I change a false to true it cannot detect.

```
| statusId  | statusName                                | statusState | isRequire            |
| 3         | Approved                                  | APPROVED    | false                |
| 201       | Attributed                                | REJECTED    | true                 |
| 202       | Denied                                    | REJECTED    | false                |
| 204       | Fraud                                     | REJECTED    | false                |
| 205       | Insufficient                              | REJECTED    | false                |
| 206       | Invalid                                   | REJECTED    | false                |
| 207       | Cancelled                                 | REJECTED    | false                |
| 208       | Cannot traced                             | REJECTED    | false                |
| 209       | Transaction online                        | REJECTED    | false                |
| 210       | Voucher                                   | REJECTED    | false                |
| 211       | does not meet req                         | REJECTED    | false                |
```

I want to write a function so that if data is those two lists are different then that can be detectected. Following is my code but seems like it always give 'false' whether data is same or different in both lists.

```
   private boolean compareLists(List<Status> actualStatuses, List<Status> expectedStatuses) {
    boolean indicator = false;
    if (actualStatuses!= null && expectedStatuses!=null && actualStatuses.size() == expectedStatuses.size()){
        for (Status expectedStatusData : expectedStatuses){
            for(Status actualStatusData : actualStatuses){
                if(actualStatusData.getStatusId() == expectedStatusData.getStatusId()
                        && actualStatusData.getStatusName().equals(expectedStatusData.getStatusName())
                        && actualStatusData.getStatusState().equals(expectedStatusData.getStatusState())
                        && actualStatusData.isEnable() == expectedStatusData.isEnable()
                        && actualClaimStatusData.isRequire() == expectedStatusData.isRequire()){
                    indicator = true;
                    break;
                }
                else indicator = false;
            }
        }
        if (indicator)
            return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

    return indicator;
}
```

Comment: You're better have `equals` (+ `hashCode`) overriden in your `Status` class, so you can avoid this big `if` line and your code would be much more readable.

Answer (score 8):

A better way of doing this (assuming the list doesn't contain repeated values) is to store all the elements of one list in a `HashSet` and then check if the `HashSet` contains all of the elements of the other list and that their sizes are the same.

```
private <E> boolean listsHaveSameElements(final List<E> l1, final List<E> l2) {
    final Set<E> set = new HashSet<>(l1);
    return l1.size() == l2.size() && set.containsAll(l2);
}
```

This is an `O(n+m)` solution while using `List.containsAll()` would need to iterate all the elements of the other list to check for existence so it would be `O(n*m)`

Comment: IMHO. If the hashcode and equals are over ridden than, Set will give performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if the sizes are equal, you could just iterate over both lists and when you find the first status in `expectedStatuses` that is not found in `actualStatuses` you can return false since the lists are not equal anymore.

However, if the lists get bigger you might run into performance issues since that's basically a O(n<sup>2</sup>) approach. In that case you could first put all expected statuses into a set and remove the actual ones afterwards. If at the end the set is not empty the lists are not equal and you'd even know which statuses are missing. If you only need to check for equality just check whether the set contains the elements of the second list. Both would be O(n) in the worst case.

Note that `List.containsAll()` does basically the same as described above, i.e. iterates over the collection parameter and for each element looks in its own list (calling `contains(e)`) and on the first element not found returns false.

Edit:

Using a set would be equally simple as `List.containsAll()`, provided your elements have their `hashCode()` and `equals()` implemented properly:

```
new HashSet<Status>( expectedStatuses ).containsAll( actualStatuses );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
private boolean compareLists(List<Status> actualStatuses, List<Status> expectedStatuses) {
    boolean listsHaveSameSize = actualStatuses.size() == expectedStatuses.size();

    return listsHaveSameSize ? actualStatuses.containsAll(expectedStatuses)
                             : false;
}
```

Comment: Should work if your objects implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T> boolean equalsIgnoreOrder(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
       return false;
    }
    Map<T, Integer> map1 = createCountMap(list1);
    Map<T, Integer> map2 = createCountMap(list2);
    return map1.equals(map2);
}

/**
 * Note that T must have a proper hashCode() and equals() for this to work
 */
private <T> Map<T, Integer> createCountMap(List<T> list) {
    Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    for (T value : list) {
        Integer prevCount = map.get(value);
        map.put(value, prevCount == null ? 1 : prevCount + 1);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Out of all the answers this is the only one that actually compares the two lists ignoring order, taking note of the duplicates in each and rejecting two lists with the same elements but different duplicates